# A Panel with FvwmButtons

Tags: window-manager, window-management, window-decorations, fvwm

I am trying to make a simple panel out of `FvwmButtons`. I want to use it instead of `FvwmTaskBar`. Because there was too many old stuff in the web I asked for Help here.

I want to **understand** `FvwmButton` and the process it involves; So I devise a scenario.

```
+--------------------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+
|                                |         |              |   Stand   |
|    FvwmIconMan                 |FvwmPager|    Xclock    |   alone   |
|                                |         |              |    Tray   |
+--------------------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

1. How to split `FvwmButtons` into this scheme?
2. How to `Swallow` this things into it?
3. How to manage The Space as it grows? (`FvwmIconMan` will grow by
   windows opened) `Auto-Resize in FvwmButtons seems not doable`
4. *How to tell the whole deal to sit at the bottom of the desktop (all the desktops) and other windows like (firefox and so on) to respect
   its place and no to go under or over it?

Comment: Looking for alternative for Q No.3